# xamarin unexpected blue line in the top of a page

Tags: c#, xamarin

developers!
I just started to learn Xamarin and I created a few pages. Its so simply. Just first page and a button to get the second page.
But when I clicked on the button I got unexpected blue line under my status bar. How can I fix it?
Thank you in advance!

This is my MainPage:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
             x:Class="HelloApp.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="MainPage.xaml"/>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Button x:Name="button1" Text="Go to Page 3" Clicked="Button_Click" />
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

This is my second Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="HelloApp.Page3">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Page3.xaml"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

This is my code for the class linked to first xaml:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace HelloApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page3());
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code for the class linked to second xaml:

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace HelloApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Page3 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page3 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are using a NavigationPage as the container for Page3 but not for your main page... so the question is do you want a NavigationPage or not....

Comment: @SushiHangover no, I don't . I just want to go to next page.

Answer (score 1):

Application.Current.MainPage = new Page3();

SoLved!

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Yes, I did! I really got that. THank you so much)